# no encuentro el fallo

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Quiero crear un código que simule la formación de dendritas con movimiento browniano, lo más sencillo posible (estoy en 1er curso de física.) Básicamente, genera una partícula en los bordes de una caja, añade un desplazamiento y comprueba si está dentro o fuera de la caja. Si está fuera, quiero que vuelva a generar una posición aleatoria. Si está dentro, que compruebe si se encuentra cerca de alguna patícula con coordenadas en las listas finales_x y finales_y. Si se encuentra lo suficientemente cerca, quiero que añada la posición a las listas anteriores y repita lo mismo con la siguiente partícula.
quiero hacer un plot de 250 particulas pero solo consigo 2 o 3. No doy con el fallo, imagino que estará en la función. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias! (es bastante urgente).

```
#imports

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
import time
print('-'*10)
print('SIMULACIÓN DE FRACTALES')
print('-'*10)
print('CARGANDO...')

#fija variable 'bucle' a 'si' (para que entre en el bucle while más abajo)

bucle='si'
#empieza a contar milisegundos desde tiempo unix
inicio=time.time()
#n particulas 
nparticulas=250



#posiciones finales

finales_x=[0]
finales_y=[0]
#-------
maxi=10

diez=maxi*ones(100,)
menosd=-1*diez
fronteras=linspace(-maxi,maxi,100)

plt.plot(fronteras,diez,'k')
plt.plot(diez,fronteras,'k')
plt.plot(fronteras,menosd,'k')
plt.plot(menosd,fronteras,'k')


#------------------
def cerca(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    
    for i in range(len(x2)):
        if sqrt((x1-x2[i])**2 + (y1-y2[i])**2)<0.3: 
            #print('a')
            return 'cerca'

                
    
    

for i in range(nparticulas):
    bucle='si'
    #genera pos iniciales
    lista=[1,2,3,4]
    movimiento=random.choice(lista)
        
    if movimiento==1:
        x_particula=random.uniform(-maxi,maxi)
        y_particula=maxi
        
    elif movimiento==2:
        x_particula=random.uniform(-maxi,maxi)
        y_particula=-maxi
        
    elif movimiento==3:
        x_particula=-maxi
        y_particula=random.uniform(-maxi,maxi)
        
    else:
        x_particula=maxi
        y_particula=random.uniform(-maxi,maxi)

    bucle='si'


    while bucle=='si':
        
        #genera posiciones aleatorias a partir de la anterior
        desplazamientox=random.random()
        
        desplazamientoy=random.random()
        
        x_particula=x_particula+desplazamientox
        
        y_particula=y_particula+desplazamientoy 
        #--------
        
        if abs(x_particula)>maxi:
            nparticulas+=1
            
            
            bucle='no'
            
            
        if abs(y_particula)>maxi:
            
            
            nparticulas+=1
            bucle='no'
            
            
        if cerca(x_particula,finales_x,y_particula,finales_y)=='cerca':
            
            finales_x.append(x_particula)
            finales_y.append(y_particula)
            bucle='no'
    
        
        
print(len(finales_x))

finales_x_array=asarray(finales_x)
finales_y_array=asarray(finales_y)
     
plt.plot(finales_x_array,finales_y_array,'b.',ms=10)
    
plt.show()

final=time.time() #cuenta ms desde tiempo unix al acabar la ejecucion


tiempo_ejecucion=final-inicio 

print('el tiempo de ejecución es %.f ms'%tiempo_ejecucion)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Y cual sería el fallo?